# CSS text-align not working

Tags: css, text-alignment, text-align

I have this css code here

```
.navigation{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#7a7a7a;
    font-size:18px;
}

.navigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.navigation li {
    float: left;
}


.navigation ul a {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 65px 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

What I am trying to do is center my class navigation. I tried using `text-align:center;` and `vertical-align:middle;` but neither of them worked.

and here is the HTML Code

```
<div class="navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://surfthecurve.ca/">home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://surfthecurve.ca/?page_id=7">about</a></li>
<li><a href="http://surfthecurve.ca/?page_id=9">tutors</a></li>
<li><a href="http://surfthecurve.ca/?page_id=11">students</a></li>
<li><a href="http://surfthecurve.ca/?page_id=13">contact us</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--navigation-->
```

When I say its not working, I mean the text is aligned to the left.

Comment: Do you want the entire 5 item navigation centred under the logo?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Change the rule on your `<a>` element from:

```
.navigation ul a {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 65px 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}​
```

to

```
.navigation ul a {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 65px 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}​
```

Just add two new rules (`width:100%;` and `text-align:center;`). You need to make the anchor expand to take up the full width of the list item and then text-align center it.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gnXcg/)**

Comment: it kinda of works, but its still not centered inside the navigation div, take a look here http://jamessuske.com/surfthecurve/

Comment: No problem. For that example I just added two rules to your `<ul>` element. `width:652px` and `margin: 0 auto;`.

Answer (score 18):

You have to make the `UL` inside the `div` behave like a block. Try adding

```
.navigation ul {
     display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I try to avoid floating elements unless the design really needs it. Because you have floated the `<li>` they are out of normal *flow*.

If you add `.navigation { text-align:center; }` and change `.navigation li { float: left; }` to `.navigation li { display: inline-block; }` then entire navigation will be centred.

One caveat to this approach is that `display: inline-block;` is not supported in IE6 and needs a workaround to make it work in IE7.